# Endless loop after upgrading to new php 7 server

Tags: php, mobile

I was using this code to redirect mobile users to my mobile site

```
$ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

$uachar = "/(nokia|sony|ericsson|mot|samsung|sgh|lg|philips|panasonic|alcatel|lenovo|cldc|midp|mobile)/i";

if(($ua == '' || preg_match($uachar, $ua))&& !strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']),'wap'))
{
    $Loaction = 'mobile/';
    if (!empty($Loaction))
    {
        ecs_header("Location: $Loaction\n");
        exit;
    }
}
```

> domain.com/mobile

Recently i have moved my server to a cloud server with PHP 7 now the issue i have started facing is when the site is accessed by mobile there is this endless loop like this

> domain.com/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/

Can someone please help me or point me in the right direction

Thanks

Comment: `if $ua is empty, or has a match from $uachar AND does not contain 'wap'` right? What does `$ua` usually hold, and what does it hold on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

You must also check that the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` doesn't start with `/mobile`. For example:

```
if (($ua == '' || preg_match($uachar, $ua)) &&
    strpos($requestUri, '/wap') === false &&
    strpos($requestUri, '/mobile') === false
) {
    $location = 'mobile/';
    header("Location: $location");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, provide answers that [don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). Also, the [StackOverflow Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) is a very helpful resource!